# Check if string contains between 1 and 3 characters of .-_ anywhere in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex that checks a string and will match a dot, dash or underscore. I only want it to allow a maximum of 3 otherwise it should not match the string.

For example if I enter `qwerty-123-123-123` that is okay.

If I enter `something-123_world` that is okay.

However if I enter `qwerty-123-_whatever-something` this should not match.

[Current regex](https://regexr.com/42om2)

My current regex matches the specific characters I want but I can't seem to figure out how to only allow 3 maximum. I thought `{1,3}` was the answer but that didn't seem to work. I also had a look at `?=` positive lookups but not sure if that's correct / even able to get it to do what I want.

Comment: Ahh that worked a treat! thanks! can you write an answer so i can upvote it and accept it please :)

Comment: @Wiktor strange smilies everywhere! `-_.`

Comment: A simple solution is to split and check length, e.g. `if (string.split(/[-_.]/).length < 5) {  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[^-_.]*(?:[-_.][^-_.]*){1,3}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SRs6NZ/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^-_.]*` - any 0+ chars other than `-`, `_` and `.`
- `(?:[-_.][^-_.]*){1,3}` - one, two or three occurrences of

  - `[-_.]` - a `-`, `_` or `.`
  - `[^-_.]*` - any 0+ chars other than `-`, `_` and `.`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

The other option apart from Regex would be to use JavaScript!

```js
let str1 = 'qwerty-123-123-123';
let str2 = 'something-123_world';
let str3 = 'qwerty-123-_whatever-something';

const regex = /[._-]/g;
let min = 1;
let max = 3;

function validate(txt) {
  var len = txt.match(regex).length;
  
  if(len >= min && len <= max) 
    return true;
  
  return false;
}

console.log(validate(str1) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid');
console.log(validate(str2) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid');
console.log(validate(str3) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid');
```